# Node module to handle optional arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am looking for a Node.js module that can handle and assign optional arguments.

For example, say I have this function signature:

```
function foo(desc, opts, cb, extra, writable) {
```

"desc" and "cb" are required, everything else is optional; this is an internal piece of code not part of a public API, but I still need a way to handle it properly. Writing the logic to handle these types of situations in a codebase is getting tricky.

Does anyone know of a good NPM module that can handle this kind of thing? Having trouble finding one.

I don't believe default params will solve this.

for example:

```
const args = ['description', function(){}, []];

foo.apply(global,args);
```

then what would happen is that if I had

```
function foo(desc, opts = {}, cb, extra, writable){}
```

then opts would take the value of the function, not the default {} value.

Right? Or wrong?

This is how I solve it for now:

```
foo: function foo(desc, opts, cb, extra, writable) {

            if (typeof desc !== 'string') {
                SumanErrors.badArgs(suman, true, new Error('Need a description for the test suite.'));
            }
            else if (typeof opts === 'function') {

                writable = extra;
                extra = cb;
                cb = opts;
                opts = {};

            }
            else {
                if (typeof desc !== 'string') {
                    SumanErrors.badArgs(suman, true, new Error('desc is not a string'));
                }
                if (typeof opts !== 'object') {
                    SumanErrors.badArgs(suman, true, new Error('opts is not an object'));
                }
                if (typeof cb !== 'function') {
                    SumanErrors.badArgs(suman, true, new Error('cb is not a function'));
                }
            }

            return {
                desc: desc,
                opts: opts,
                cb: cb,
                extra: extra,
                writable: writable
            }
        }
```

An NPM module could be written to handle this type of thing, as long as the function signature conformed to certain rules. The above doesn't look so bad, but it can get a lot trickier.

Comment: "Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Also, you can use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) if you pass the `--harmony_default_parameters` flag.

Comment: May be you can put desc and cb as first two arguments. Then you can have rest of them as optional.

Comment: Lastly, no module would be able to solve this. To pass a `cb` value, you would need to pass *something* for `opts`, even if you just passed `undefined`. JS has no way of knowing you meant the second value to be passed as the third argument. You could rewrite the function to take an object which would allow you to use "named" arguments.

Comment: Mike a library could be written as long as all the arguments had different types; but otherwise yes you are correct.

Comment: @AlexMills It doesn't matter what the types are, it's the ordering. See my answer.

Comment: You seem to be quite against the idea of just changing the function signature or ensuring that you receive the arguments in the correct order. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand the need for an `npm` module -- if you are using ES2015, you can just assign default parameters in your method declarations (see [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)).

Comment: I don't think default params will solve this, will try to explain why. Could be  wrong.

Comment: If you're not making the required parameters first, then yes you're right. I would change the order of the arguments so that anything "optional" is toward the end. Alternatively, I'd use a single object as the parameter -- that way every key on the object is optional without breaking the number of arguments (and their order).

Comment: Yeah but it's not always that simple. Essentially what I am doing above is contructing an options object. Constructing an options object prior to this is actually the same problem exact problem, if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, arguments and parameters are determined exclusively based on their position.

```
function test(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a); // 1
  console.log(b); // 2
  console.log(c); // 3
}
test(1, 2, 3);
```

Meaning, there's no way to make this work:

```
function test(a, b, c) {
  b = defaultValue(b); // Assign some default value to b
  console.log(a); // 1
  console.log(b); // 'Default'
  console.log(c); // 2
}
test(1, 2);
```

The semantics of the language do not allow it, period. You could instead choose to change the order of your parameters. If you make all required parameters come first and the last ones optional then it will work as intended.

```
function test(a, b, c) {
  c = defaultValue(c); // Assign some default value to c
  console.log(a); // 1
  console.log(b); // 2
  console.log(c); // 'Default'
}
test(1, 2);
```

This works with any number of optional parameters.

```
function test(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) {
  c = defaultValue(c);
  ...
  i = defaultValue(i);
  console.log(a); // 1
  console.log(b); // 2
  console.log(c); // 'Default'
  ...
  console.log(i); // 'Default'
}
test(1, 2);
```

If you don't want to rearrange the order of the parameters, you can create pseudo-named arguments by passing an object.

```
function test(opts) {
  fillInDefaults(opts);
  console.log(opts.a); // 1
  console.log(opts.b); // 'Default'
  console.log(opts.c); // 2
  console.log(opts.d); // 'Default'
}
test({
  a: 1,
  c: 2
});
```

Comment: the problem is if there are 2 or more optional arguments at the end of the function signature, we have the same problem to solve ! Likewise, constructing an options object *before* passing the parameters to the function actually provides us with the same exact problem to solve, as I noted to Arthur Kay. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: @AlexMills There's no problem if there are 2 or more optional arguments. You could call `test(1, 2)` and `test` could take (theoretically) an infinite number of optional parameters at the end and it would work just fine. Constructing an options object before hand doesn't provide that problem at all unless you are given the parameters in an array from an outside source with no information about which parameters they intended to pass to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a general purpose solution to this problem:

https://github.com/ORESoftware/pragmatik

If anyone knows of someone who has already tried to do this, please let me know. In my less than exhaustive search, I haven't found anything.

"pragmatik" allows you to define *required* and *optional* arguments, default values for optional arguments, and will place the values in the correct place in the arguments list, given the rules you define.

Realistically, for the limited number of functions that accept varargs in your public/private APIs, it will be worth it to do the extra configuration to avoid writing your own code to do the cumbersome, error-prone task of correctly parsing contingent arguments.

(The usage of this library is made possible by destructuring assignment of arrays; it would be a little too inconvenient to use otherwise)